# Convert a range of numbers in Quartz Composer

Tags: math, expression, range, quartz-composer

In Quartz Composzer I have a range of incoming numbers in the range 0 to 1, and I need to convert the range to -1 to 1.  There are basic math operators or mathematical expressions I can use in patches which can be linked in any combination to achieve this.
What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get x in the range of [0, 1], just output y = 2*(x-.5).  The y value is in the range of [-1, 1].